# GWT - Horizontal scroll bar resets when scrolling vertically

Tags: internet-explorer, gwt

We have a table of data, made with a DataGrid,  with horizontal and vertical scrollbars.

If we scroll the table to the right, and then scroll the table down using the down scroll button, the horizontal scroll bar will, about half the time, jump back to the start position.

This only appears to happen in internet explorer, and not Firefox, and only every other time that we move the horizontal scroll.

If we log the sequence of event, we get a MOUSEDOWN, BLUR and then MOUSEUP event sequence. If the jump doesn't happen, the event sequence is MOUSEDOWN, MOUSEUP.

We can "fix" this by resetting the horizontal scroll bar, but this causes the screen to jump noticeably.

The vertical slider is a separate widget, while the horizontal slider is part of the data grid.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening, and what we can do to fix it?